# Download files from url using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a generated url that will need to open up the browser to download the file from the server. I am trying to simulate this download using Python requests library

import requests

```
url = r'https://www.filedownloadserver.com?docId=7700915281958&projectNumber=aaa' 
resp = requests.get(url, verify=False)
    
    with open('test.pdf', 'wb') as file:
         file.write(chunk)
```

the output pdf file is incorrect, from the resp.content, it returns javascript that looks like this

```
//<script>location.href=('https://login.fileserver.com/login1/?redirect='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));</script> location.href=('https://login.fileserver.com/login1/?redirect='+encodeURIComponent(location.href));
```

is there anyway I can get the actual file from the above content?

Comment: It is apparent from the response content that you are required to authenticate before you are allowed to download the file.

Comment: thanks for the advice, you're right, i will need to login!